# Update Exist Data Using DataRow C#

Tags: mysql, datarow

I need to update my exist data in mysql database.

I write like this code;

```
        String _id = lbID.Text;
        dsrm_usersTableAdapters.rm_usersTableAdapter _t = new dsrm_usersTableAdapters.rm_usersTableAdapter();
        dsrm_users _mds = new dsrm_users();
        _mds.EnforceConstraints = false;

        dsrm_users.rm_usersDataTable _m = _mds.rm_users;

        _t.FillBy4(_m, _id);
        if(_m.Rows.Count >0 )
        {

            DataRow _row = _m.Rows[0];

             _row.BeginEdit();

            _row["username"] = txtUserName.Text;

            _row.EndEdit();

            _row.AcceptChanges();

            _t.Update(_m);

        }
```

But nothing change my exists data. What is the Problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows

Yes I move the AccesptChange() after update bu now its give this error

Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows

But now problem is, I use MySQL and I can not Wrie UpdateCommand , VS2008 does not accept the SQL command. Automaticly delete all SQL command. I dont understand the problem. So do you now another way without using SQL command (UpdateCommand) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you call DataRow.AcceptChanges() before calling DbDataAdapter.Update(). AcceptChanges will set the status of the datarow to "orignal" (or "not changed" - I don't remeber now). Try to move the call to AcceptChanges to after the Update.